# AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger' when creating a new environment

Tags: python, django, flask

I was trying to create a new virtual environment using python. but when I executed the command `python3 -m venv env`

It shows the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/venv/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import os, glob, subprocess, os.path, time, pwd, sys, requests_unixsocket
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_unixsocket/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .retry import Retry
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 20, in <module>
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/venv/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'
```

This is the same case if i type `pip list` without getting into any virtual environment.

as far as i remember I haven't installed anything globally in my local machine.

can anyone help?

Comment: If you called one of your files `logging.py`, pick a different name.

Comment: But this happens when I try to create a new environment. There is no logging.py.

Comment: `python3 -c 'import logging; print(logging.__file__)'` and show us what that prints.

Comment: Running this command shows None.

Comment: ...something is *seriously* wrong with your Python setup.

Comment: Does this mean that I should re install python?

Comment: Considering that the error message looks like you might be using the system Python, I'm worried you might end up having to wipe your system and reinstall the OS. I suggest backing up your data now, in case it comes to that.

Comment: data is backed up. can you suggest how can i fix this?